# How do I print dates in latex without defining them first?

Tags: datetime

I want `\date{2015-10-10}` to print `10th October, 2015` or similar. I don't want to separate the date value from the place where it is inserted into the document.

Answer (score 2):

Along the same lines as the other answer (save it and immediately print it in a macro), but using `datetime2` for formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-US]{datetime2}
\newcommand{\mydate}[1]{
    \DTMsavedate{newdate}{#1}
    \DTMusedate{newdate}
}
\begin{document}
\mydate{2015-10-10}

\mydate{2015-01-01}
\end{document}
```

Prints:

> October 10, 2015
>
> January 1, 2015

Answer (score 1):

The `\date` command does not print the date, it stores its argument on the `\@date` macro. Macros with `@`, to be used must be enclosed within `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Knowing this you can make a command which takes an argument, pass it to `\date` and prints it afterwards:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\printdate}[1]{\date{#1}\@date}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text \printdate{2015-12-12} \printdate{2014-12-12}
\end{document}
```

Note that this is an overall solution and depending on the packages you are using could not give the expected results.

Comment: But I believe that would print the date as given, not convert it to "December 12th, 2015".  Yes?

Comment: I'm not sure if  that would happen *always*. In this case yes as there's no packages involved.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `british` language setting for [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2), you can set your date style using `\DTMdisplaydate{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{DoW}` or `\DTMdate{YYYY-MM-DD}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[british,calc]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=raise}

\DTMnewdatestyle{mydate}{%
  % #1 = year
  % #2 = month
  % #3 = day
  % #4 = day of week
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMordinal{##3} \DTMenglishmonthname{##2}, \number##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\today% ...or \DTMtoday

% \DTMdisplaydate{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{DOW}
\DTMdisplaydate{2015}{10}{10}{-1}

% \DTMdate{YYYY-MM-DD}
\DTMdate{2015-10-10}

\DTMsetdatestyle{mydate}% Set new date style
\DTMdate{2015-10-10}

\end{document}
```